# Hand of the Mage with +2 Wisdom

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

Ok,
I haven't been in touch with magic item creation in  a while.
So what would a hand of the mage further enchanted with +2 Wisdom cost?
Assuming I have an enchanter capable and willing to do the enchanting(he is an npc).
 
From what I remember it would have been 900 for the base item and 6000 (1.5 * 4000) with Dungeon Masters Guide - Rules, but I am not sure wether the Magic Item Compendium changed that.

Hand of the Mage can be found [here](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Hand_of_the_Mage) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Magic Item Compendium* eliminated the cost-penalty associated with combining items for the following types of effects:

- Deflection bonus to AC
- Armor bonus to AC
- Enhancement bonus to natural armor bonus to AC
- Enhancement bonuses to ability scores
- Resistance bonuses to saving throws
- Resistance to energy

With that being the case, your *+2 Wisdom hand of the mage* would cost simply 900 gp for *hand of the mage* plus 4,000 gp for the *periapt of wisdom +2*, so 4,900 gp. Under the original rules, you would multiply the cheaper portion of the item (the *hand of the mage*) by 1½, so you’ have 4,000 + 1½×900 = 5,350 gp.

Comment: does that mean, that I could add a deflection bonus to that hand of the mage in addition to the wisdom without paying any additional costs besides the base cost for the deflection bonus?

Comment: @Andy Yes, it does. The cost for doing so is in *Magic Item Compendium* but it's in line with what you see for items that do that in the DMG.